# How to use superset's mapbox view when longitude and latitude are in postgis point format?

Tags: postgis, apache-superset

I am trying to make an apache superset chart with map box view.
I have to set latitude and longitude columns. But these data are in a postgresql + postgis database. So, latitude and longitude are in the same column location. An sql query would be like this:

`SELECT ST_X(location), ST_Y(location) FROM Address`

How can I make superset get latitude with the function `ST_X()`?

Comment: I did't get your question very well. You want to list **only** the longitude values for all records, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox also supports other geometry flavours, such as **[WKT](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wkt-crs)** (Well Known Text) and **[GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/)**, so it is normally not necessary to split them in *X,Y* or *Y,X* pairs.

To retrieve GeoJSON from PostgreSQL (+PostGIS):

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(location) FROM t;
```

And as WKT:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(location) FROM t;
```

Comment: My issue is with apache superset charts. If I understood well, I have to select a column for latitudes and a column for longitudes. And it seems that I can not use these functions for querying.

Comment: Your query is actually right! Maybe you're missing an alias for each column, so that the system can distinguish them better? `SELECT ST_X(location) AS lon, ST_Y(location) AS lat FROM Address`

Comment: Thanks but my problem is with apache superset. The chart module with mapbox template does not seem to accept these kind of queries. I only found a form where I select a column for latitudes and a column for longitudes. And I want to make it accept a query like what we wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Superset makes it possible to create "virtual" columns in tables.So I created columns latitude with this expression:
ST_X(location)
And that worked
thanks to this superset team:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/4640#event-1527353388